# how to add a javascript event in a formset?

Tags: python, django

I want to add an **onchange event to the formset**, I tried to do this in **views.py**, but it adds this error to me:

```
'name':input(attrs={
TypeError: input() takes no keyword arguments
```

> views.py

```
    ParteFormSet = formset_factory(ParteForm, extra=extra_forms, max_num=20, widgets={
        'name':input(attrs={
            'onchange': 'multiplicar()'
        })
    })
    formset = ParteFormSet()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to define the widget in the parent form ('ParteForm'), not in the formset_factory function.

Second, `input()` is not a Django widget. Actually, you're invoking Python's input() function, which is definitely not what you want.

Instead use a valid Django built-in widget class (see list [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/widgets/#built-in-widgets)). For example, `forms.TextInput()`.